# If/else in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to return random word from file, based on passed argument. But if the argument doesn't match anythning I dont want to return anything. My method looks like:

```
def word_from_score(self,score):
    print(random.choices([word for word in self.file if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score]))
```

It returns the correct word from file based on passed argument in command line, but if the argument doesnt match, i want to return nothing, like ''. How could I add else to this statement?

Comment: Pleae provide a [MCVE] with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
def word_from_score(self,score):
    print(random.choices([(word if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score else "") for word in self.file]))
```

The `(... if ... else ...)` is actually the ternary operator and not part of the surrounding list comprehension.

Comment: EDIT: it doesnt work, atm it returns " even if in file is word which sum of letter is passed in argument

Comment: @Frendom (1) Have you checked that it works with your original function? (2) Can you give a simple example for testing?